# How to replace a word ending in something with another word in a file

Tags: if-statement, awk

I have a file called sentry.tmp with structure

```
8272275 docliente_up/ant_aux_secciones_mes2 556321
8272276 docliente_up/ant_aux_ufcp_mes1  556322
8272278 docliente_up/ant_aux_ufcp_mes2  556324
8272460 docliente_up/jmn_sms_sevilla    556471
8837577 docliente_bu/do_acumulacion/fecha=20190502  550972
8837578 docliente_tres/do_acumulacion/fecha=20190524    550972
8837579 docliente/do_acumulacion/fecha=20190503 550972
```

I like to add the word `databases` before words ending in `_up/` that are in the beginning of the second columns, and the others add the word `databases_users`.

Something like this:

```
8272275 databases/docliente_up/ant_aux_secciones_mes2   556321
8272276 databases/docliente_up/ant_aux_ufcp_mes1    556322
8272278 databases/docliente_up/ant_aux_ufcp_mes2    556324
8272460 databases/docliente_up/jmn_sms_sevilla  556471
8837577 databases_users/docliente_bu/do_acumulacion/fecha=20190502  550972
8837578 databases_users/docliente_tres/do_acumulacion/fecha=20190524    550972
8837579 databases_users/docliente/do_acumulacion/fecha=20190503 550972
```

I have a file that have the name of the first word of the second column.

```
$cat init.txt
 docliente_up
 docliente_bu
 docliente_tres
 docliente
```

and I use this code but I can't find the way to do it.

```
for i in `awk '{print $2}' $wkdir/init.txt`
 do 
if  [[ "$i" == *_up ]]
 then 
  awk -v basedatos=$i '{gsub(/$basedatos/,"databases/$basedatos");}1' sentry.tmp >sentry.new
 else 
  awk -v basedatos=$i '{gsub(/$basedatos/,"databases_users/$basedatos");}1' sentry.tmp >>sentry.new
 fi
done
```

Comment: Could you please explain about file `init.txt`, not sure about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{$2=$2 ~ /_up\//?"databases/"$2:"databases_users/"$2} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{$2 = "databases" ($2 ~ "_up/" ? "" : "_users") "/" $2} 1' file
8272275 databases/docliente_up/ant_aux_secciones_mes2 556321
8272276 databases/docliente_up/ant_aux_ufcp_mes1 556322
8272278 databases/docliente_up/ant_aux_ufcp_mes2 556324
8272460 databases/docliente_up/jmn_sms_sevilla 556471
8837577 databases_users/docliente_bu/do_acumulacion/fecha=20190502 550972
8837578 databases_users/docliente_tres/do_acumulacion/fecha=20190524 550972
```